# RestEasy client: How to wrap list elements?

Tags: rest, jaxb, client, resteasy

I am trying to create RestEasy client for RestEasy REST service, providing this entity:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity @Table(name="product")
@XmlRootElement(name="product")
public class Product implements Serializable, IHasTraits {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "INT UNSIGNED")
    private Long id;
```

The result is

```
[{"id":1,"name":"FOO","note":null,...}]
```

Then I try to read it through an interface.
I would expect that the same model class could be used.

```
@Path("/")
public interface RestClient {

    @GET
    @Path("/products")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<Product> getProducts();
```

Using

```
    RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());
    this.client = ProxyFactory.create(RestClient.class, "http://localhost:8080/essc-portal/rest");
```

But the client throws:

> Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
>    - with linked exception:
>   [com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; columnNumber: 0; unexpected element (uri:"", local:"id"). Expected elements are <{}product>]

I've tried to add

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="product")
```

or

```
@XmlElement(type = Product.class, name = "product")
```

or

```
@org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.jaxb.Wrapped(element = "product")
```

But neither did help.

How should I solve this? I'd prefer not to create additional bean class.

Answer (score 0):

What RestEasy client expects is:

```
  [{"product":{"id":1,"name":"EAP","note":null,"extIdJira":null,"extIdBugzilla":"226"}]
```

not

```
  {"products":[{"id":1,"name":"EAP","note":null,"extIdJira":null,"extIdBugzilla":"226"}]}
```

So I ended up with changed producing method:

```
public List<ProductWrapper> getProducts( @Context SecurityContext sc ) {
    final List<Product> prods = daoProd.getProducts_orderName(0);
    return rewrap(prods);
}
```

and

```
private List<ProductWrapper> rewrap(List<Product> prods) {
    List<ProductWrapper> p2 = new ArrayList(prods.size());
    for( Product product : prods){
        p2.add( new ProductWrapper(product));
    }
    return p2;
}
```